# Boost upgrade from 1.42 to 1.61

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, linker

We were using boost 1.42 in our project and we have to migrate to using boost 1.61 because of company policy. I replaced references from boost 1.42 to boost 1.61 in our make files, and did a compilation. I encountered many boost related errors as many boost method names have been deprecated from boost 1.42 to boost 1.61 and I fixed those compilation errors. However, after fixing these, now compilation is going through with boost 1.61 but I am encountering the following linking error --
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_signals-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib'

On comparing the lib files of boost (1.42 and 1.61) I see that libboost_signals-vcxx-zzzz.lib is there only in boost version 1.42 and not in boost 1.61. So why is the linker trying to link to  libboost_signals-vcxx-zzz.lib. Is there any way I can debug this to understand which piece of code is leading to this linking error ?

Comment: Maybe this is not an "unresolved symbol" linker error, but your makefile tells the linker to link this library which does not exist anymore?

Comment: Thanks, good point, I will check my make files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .lib files do not ship with Boost; you build them yourself. You probably also did this a few years ago for 1.42, but you now need to do it for 1.61.

[Build instructions for Boost 1.61 on Windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some boost library that you are using depends on signals or still in some makefile. It is missing in your 1.1 directory and needs to be there. It is in this package:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.61.0/boost_1_61_0-msvc-14.0-64.exe/download